# Django __iregex crashing for regular expression ^(\\. \\.)$

Tags: sql, django, regex, database, psql

When I try to make an `__iregex` call using the regular expression `'^(\\. \\.)$'` I get:

`DataError: invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced`

I am using PSQL backend so the django documentation states that the equivalent SQL command should be

`SELECT ... WHERE title ~* '^(\\. \\.)$';`

When I run this query manually through the PSQL command line it works fine. Is there some bug with Django that I don't know about that is causing this to crash?

Edit: Also, it fails for variations of this regular expression, for example
`'^(S\\. \\.)$'`
`'^(\\. S\\.)$'`
`'^(\\. \\.S)$'`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to replace all `" "` characters with `\s` before sending the regexp into `__iregex`.